# package import problem in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In mathematica (I am using mma 5.0 ( guess pretty old)), if I type the following as one line:

```
Needs["Graphics`Master`"]; Animate[Plot[Sin[n x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> False], {n, 1, 6, 1}]
```

I then got a lot of errors/warnings. But if I type them in separately, it is working fine. How to make it work in one code block?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

As belisarius points out, your question as it stands is a bit v5-centric. The problem, however, still exists in current versions. As an example

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
ToCycles[{3, 4, 1, 2}]
```

works fine, while (after restarting the kernel),

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]; ToCycles[{3, 4, 1, 2}]
```

fails with an error that

> "ToCycles::shdw: Symbol ToCycles
>   appears in multiple contexts
>   {Combinatorica`,Global`}; definitions
>   in context Combinatorica` may shadow
>   or be shadowed by other definitions."

In Mathematica terms, the reason the one-liner doesn't work is that Mathematica tries to resolve all symbols in the line before evaluating `Needs` (this was a surprise to me). This resolves `ToCycles` to `` Global`ToCycles `` (thus entering this symbol in the symbol table), before `Needs` gets a chance to load the definition of `` Combinatorica`ToCycles `` and add `Combinatorica` to the [`$ContextPath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24ContextPath.html). To make the one-liner work, you must use the full name of `ToCyles`:

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]; Combinatorica`ToCycles[{3, 4, 1, 2}]
```

---

**To understand** the error, you need to know that all Symbols in Mathematica have a [full name](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Contexts.html) of the form `` context`name ``. A context is similar to a namespace in many other languages. Now, if a symbol (such as `ToCycles`) is referenced without a context, Mathematica will look through the contexts currently in `$ContextPath` and see if the symbol is defined in any of those contexts. If not, the symbol is resolved in the current context, `$Context` which is `Global` in normal use.
When you load a package, the symbols of that package are defined in a package context (e.g. `Combinatorica`), and when the package is fully loaded this context is added to the `$ContextPath` so that you can access the symbols by their short name.
Now, you can see what the error means: Since the `Combinatorica` has not yet been loaded when the symbols are resolved, `ToCycles` resolves to `` Global`ToCycles ``. After the package loads, Mathematica helpfully checks that all short names are unique, and finds in this case that the short name `ToCycles` is now defined in two contexts on `$ContextPath` one thus "shadowing" the other. To refer to a specific of these symbols, you must use the full name, e.g. `` Combinatorica`ToCycles ``.

To resolve a shadow conflict, simply `Remove` the unwanted symbol:

```
Remove[Global`ToCycles]
```

Don't know how readable this was, but hope it helps a bit...

Comment: @Janus: how to use Combinatorica'ToCycles? Also, how to resolve the issue of writing Needs and the ToCycles in the same code block? Many thanks!

Comment: Well explained! It is a bit surprising that the naive 1-liner doesn't work.

Comment: @Quang Li: It has to be a "backtick" between Combinatorica and ToCycles, but it took me a while to figure out how to enter a literal backtick in my answer. Should be ok now? Also, I added the correct one-liner before I even saw your comment :)

Comment: @Simon: Thanks! It surprised me as well. Always thought that semicolons and line breaks were completely interchangeable...

Comment: +10 Never happened to me ... just because I always use Needs[] in a line on its own ... Good to know why!

Comment: Turns out that `;` is actually a shorthand for `CompoundExpression` which I guess is why things are different. Still, symbol resolution isn't really included in http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Evaluation.html :)

Comment: @Janus: pay attention that semicolons and line breaks are not interchangeable in another way: `1;<line break> (% + 1)` will return `2`, while `1; (% + 1)` will return something that depends on your previous results.

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to put the `Needs[]` call(s) at the top of a notebook in a separate block, or on the first isolated line of a package.m file.

The kernel reads the whole line and parses it, including deciding on the contexts for symbols, before beginning to evaluate it.  To avoid problems, do not use semicolons.  Put *two* newlines after every statement in a package.
Especially after the `BeginPackage[]` and/or `Needs[]`.