# Accidental shadowing and `Removed[symbol]`

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

If you evaluate the following code twice, results will be different. Can anyone explain what's going on?

```
findHull[points_] := Module[{},
   Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"];
   ConvexHull[points]
   ];
findHull[RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]];
Remove["Global`ConvexHull"];
findHull[RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that even though the module is not evaluated untill you call `findHull`, the symbols are resolved when you define `findHull` (i.e.: The new downvalue for `findHull` is stored in terms of symbols, not text).
This means that during the first round, `ConvexHull` resolves to `` Global`ConvexHull ``  because the `Needs` is not evaluated. 
During the second round, `ComputationalGeometry` is on `$ContextPath` and so `ConvexHull` resolves as you intended.

If you really cannot bear to load `ComputationalGeometry` beforehand, just refer to `ConvexHull` by its full name: `` ComputationalGeometry`ConvexHull ``. See also [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664091/package-import-problem-in-mathematica/4664741#4664741).

HTH

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Another context gotcha I found is that functions defined inside functions inside package MyPackage are put into Private' rather than MyPackage'Private'

Comment: @Yaroslav. Can't reproduce that one -- did you remember to use Begin["&#96;Private&#96;"] instead of Begin["Private`"] (because if you didn't, that would lead to exactly the behaviour you describe)?

Comment: I'll try again with the backtick quoting :) You should be using Begin["\`Private\`"].

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer to the question, but a bit too large for a comment. As another alternative, a general way to delay the symbol parsing until run-time is to use `Symbol["your-symbol-name"]`. In your case, you can replace `ConvexHull` on the r.h.s. of your definition by `Symbol["ConvexHull"]`:

```
findHull[points_] := 
 Module[{}, 
    Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"];
    Symbol["ConvexHull"][points]];
```

This solution is not very elegant though, since `Symbol["ConvexHull"]` will be executed every time afresh. This can also be somewhat error-prone, if you do non-trivial manipulations with `$ContextPath`. Here is a modified version, combined with a generally useful trick with self-redefinition, that I use in similar cases:

```
Clear[findHull];
findHull[points_] :=
Module[{},
  Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"];
  With[{ch = Symbol["ConvexHull"]},
    findHull[pts_] := ch[pts];
    findHull[points]]];
```

For example,

```
findHull[RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]]

{4, 10, 9, 1, 6, 2, 5}
```

What happens is that the first time the function is called, the original definition with `Module` gets replaced by the inner one, and that happens already after the needed package is loaded and its context placed on the `$ContextPath`. Here we exploit the fact that Mathematica replaces an old definition with a new one if it can determine that the patterns are the same - as it can in such cases.

Other instances when self-redefinition trick is useful are cases when, for example, a function call results in some expensive computation, which we want to cache, but we are not sure whether or not the function will be called at all. Then, such construct allows to cache the computed (say, symbolically) result automatically upon the first call to the function.

Comment: Nice trick! And some extra words for the sake of character counting :)

Comment: @Janus That was spot on, verbosity is one of my sins :)

Comment: Apologies for cryptic comment: the "extra words" were put in because "Nice trick!" is not long enough to qualify as an SO comment -- I think your answer is at just the right level of verbosity :)