# Mathematica function turns red, does not work

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica, minimum-spanning-tree

I'm trying to find the minimum spanned tree using Mathematica and I want to use the MinimumSpanningTree function from Combinatorica. I'm using the following code.

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"] 
MinimumSpanningTree[GraphPlot[m]]
```

where m is a matrix. However, MinimumSpanningTree turns red and does not work. The output gives

```
out = MinimumSpanningTree[<maximum spanned tree>]  //can't show the tree here
```

How can I make the MinimumSpanningTree work? Why does it turn red?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The functions turn red when you run into the so-called shadowing problem. You can read more about it in the  [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ContextsAndPackages.html). This problem is discussed in many places, in particular in the book by Roman Maeder "Programming in Mathematica". A very nice and detailed account on shadowing is the article by David Wagner in Mathematica Journal, available [here](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v6i2/columns/wagner/wagner62.pdf) as pdf. To understand this issue, you will need some basic understanding of contexts and pacakges. The following past SO discussions may also be helpful:

[Making Mathematica packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633180/making-mathematica-packages)

[Package import problem in mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664091/package-import-problem-in-mathematica)

Basically, some of the `` Combinatorica` `` functions have the same name as the new system graph-related functions of version 8, so Mathematica does not know which ones to call. If you really want to use `` Combinatorica` `` functions, then you will first need to "silently" load `` Combinatorica` `` without having it on the `$ContextPath` afterwards, which is probably most easily accomplished as

```
Block[{$ContextPath}, Needs["Combinatorica`"]]
```

Then, you will have to refer to the functions of `` Combinatorica` `` by their long names, such as `` Combinatorica`MinimumSpanningTree ``. One more thing to keep in mind is that a graph representation in `` Combinatorica` `` is different from that in the built-in v.8 functionality, so you may need to transform one into another if you want to mix those.

Answer (score 5):

I think you'll want to convert to a graph as below.

```
MinimumSpanningTree[FromAdjacencyMatrix[m]]
```

Also possibly of interest:

http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ConnectingTownsUsingKruskalsAlgorithm/